# Flickr gem : how to access user details?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, flickr

https://github.com/ctagg/flickr/tree/master

I'm trying the example in the home page of the `GEM Flickr`.

```
require 'flickr'
flickr = Flickr.new('MY_KEY')    
user = flickr.users('sco@scottraymond.net')   

user.name                                    
user.location
```

While I'm able to get the user object, I can't get any of the other attributes like name, location etc.  How to get those details?

Comment: I am attempting to help you out, however, I am getting an error when attempting to use the API: "ArgumentError: File does not exist" If I can work through this, I will be more than happy to help :-)

Comment: It is probably because of the xml gem.  You need another gem called xmlsimple.

gem install xmlsimple

Also, look for this line in the flickr gem, in the file flickr.rb 

@host='http://flickr.com' and change it to

@host='http://api.flickr.com'

Comment: Yeah, the other gem was installed properly, but I needed to change that line. Found it on his website :-)

Answer (score 0):

I worked through the problem I was experiencing above in my comment but I am not having difficulty getting people's attributes. The following code works as expected in a `ruby script/console` session:

```
require 'flickr'

f = Flickr.new('<<MY_KEY>>')

u = f.users('sco@scottraymond.net')

puts u.name
puts u.location
```

Substituting my username `('topherfangio')` instead of Scott's, the `name` attribute works, but apparently my location is nil.

Could you describe a little bit more about exactly what you are getting? Any errors or is it just blank? Have you tried multiple users?

**Edit 1:** Just got your API key and it doesn't work for me either, try the following and see if that makes any difference. Also, are you using a non-commercial key or a commercial key?

```
f = Flickr.new(:api_key => 'MY_KEY', :shared_secret => 'MY_SECRET')
```

My guess is that it's not fully authenticating or something like that.

**Edit 2:** I'm a freaking liar...I was typing `f = Flickr.new(...); f.name` which was breaking. Your API key is working correctly for me. Perhaps it's your network or something?

Comment: Just a note: obviously replace <<MY_KEY>> with your actual API key. I'm sure you know this, but in case someone else comes along later and gets confused :-)

Comment: no, I tried with your name too, still not working.  simply gives me an error Invalid API key (Key not found)

Comment: Aha! Are you sure your key is valid and you're not copying any whitespace?

Comment: do the other attributes work for you? like groups, contacts, favorites etc?

Comment: You can view your keys or apply for one at http://www.flickr.com/services/api/keys/

Comment: Key is valid, I double checked

Comment: @unknown Yes, the other attributes work just fine. However, if I don't enter the correct API key, I get the invalid message.

Comment: If you don't mind sharing it, can you send me your API key to (fangiotophia at gmail dot com) and I'll test it? I promise I won't use it for anything else :-)

Comment: Check Edit 1 for more info :-)

Comment: Just shot you an e-mail with an example (including your API key) that works properly for me.

Answer (score 0):

To not entirely answer your question, I've been using the Fleakr gem and found it to be extremely straightforward. 
Documentation is good and you do everything in the code once it is installed.

No tricks, just sudo gem install fleakr

It depends on the builder gem, so also do sudo gem install builder.

Once I switched to Fleakr my project finished quickly!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the flickr gem isn't being maintained.  Uninstall the gem by doing a `gem uninstall flickr`, then install a more up to date branch of it by doing a `gem install moonpxi-flickr`